# What is the formula for c_v coherence?

Tags: topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I've recently been playing around with Gensim LDAModel. I use coherence to evaluate the results. Gensim offers a few coherence measures. This includes `c_v` and `u_mass`.

While there is a lot of materials describing `u_mass` on the web, I could not find anything interesting on `c_v`. There must be some significant difference sice `c_v` is always positive and `u_mass` is always negative.

I'd really like to understand the `c_v` measure, could you please provide me with the exact formula for calculating the `c_v` measure?

Comment: This article http://www.saf21.eu/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/5004a165.pdf, section ***B. Topic Coherence Measurement***, explains well the formula of the c_v coherence. Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In
[This paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8259775) , c_v measure is explained and these three equations are used to describe it.

[image: equations from the paper]

I hope this is helpful to you and anyone who comes back to this post

Comment: The notation of that paper is just horrible, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't succeed to find an exact formula, but here is at least more precise description:

> CV is based on a sliding window, a one-set segmentation of the top
>   words and an indirect confirmation measure that uses normalized
>   pointwise mutual information (NPMI) and the cosinus similarity.
>
> This coherence measure retrieves cooccurrence counts for the given
>   words using a sliding window and the window size 110. The counts are
>   used to calculated the NPMI of every top word to every other top word,
>   thus, resulting in a set of vectors—one for every top word. The
>   one-set segmentation of the top words leads to the calculation of the
>   similarity between every top word vector and the sum of all top word
>   vectors. As similarity measure the cosinus is used. The coherence is
>   the arithmetic mean of these similarities. (Note that this was the
>   best coherence measure in our evalution.)

Source: http://palmetto.aksw.org/palmetto-webapp/

Answer (score 1):

The c_v coherence measure was proposed and described in a systematic framework of coherence measures by [Röder et al.](https://svn.aksw.org/papers/2015/WSDM_Topic_Evaluation/public.pdf)

> The best performing coherence measure [...] is a new combination found
> by systematic study of the configuration space of coherence measures.
> This measure (CV) combines the indirect cosine measure with the NPMI
> and the boolean sliding window. This combination has been overlooked
> so far in the literature.

I recommend to read the original paper to understand the different steps (segmentation, probability calculation, confirmation measure and aggregation) behind this measure and others, such as u_mass, c_uci or c_npmi, as well. The authors use a consistent notation to describe all coherence measures in a systematic framework. You will find the formulas in the [paper](https://svn.aksw.org/papers/2015/WSDM_Topic_Evaluation/public.pdf).

⚠️ However, there are a [couple](https://github.com/dice-group/Palmetto/issues/13) [of issues](https://github.com/dice-group/Palmetto/issues/12) with this coherence measure.
Therefore, the authors [don't recommend to use it](https://palmetto.demos.dice-research.org) anymore.

> It's not recommended to use CV because there are known issues associated with it.

Röder, M., Both, A., & Hinneburg, A. (2015). Exploring the space of topic coherence measures. WSDM 2015 - Proceedings of the 8th ACM International Conference on Web Search and Data Mining, 399–408. https://doi.org/10.1145/2684822.2685324

Comment: How did you paste in that yellow warning sign?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen ⚠️ is the [Warning emoji](https://emojipedia.org/warning/)

Comment: As B.Liu mentioned, I simply copied and pasted it from emojipedia

Comment: @J.Schneider, can you clarify whether the problems are with `c_v` itself, or just with the Palmetto implementation?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know the answer and [M. Röder neither:](https://github.com/dice-group/Palmetto/issues/13#issuecomment-371553052): "So finally I would suggest to use C_P, NPMI or UCI for evaluating topics."

Comment: It is worth noting that a fix back in 2022 seem to have fixed the said issue in the Palmetto implementation.

Comment: Reviewers:  Please read the linked issues, they have since been fix, which makes the statement in this answer false.  Edits are necessary, do not disapprove edit mindlessly...

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm remained vague to me until I dove into the code. See my [blogpost](https://medium.com/@emilrijcken/c%E1%B5%A5-topic-coherence-explained-fc70e2a85227) to walk through the mathematics of cᵥ step-by-step. In words, I would describe it as follows:

In cᵥ coherence, each topic word is compared with the set of all topics. A boolean sliding window of size 110 is used to assess whether two words co-occur. Then, the confirmation measure consists of a direct- and indirect confirmation. That is, for all N most probable words per topic, a ‘word vector’ of size N is created in which each cell contains the Normalized Pointwise Mutual Information (NPMI) between that word and word i, i in{1,2,…,N}. Then, all the word vectors in a topic are aggregated into one big topic vector. The average of all the cosine similarities between each topic word and its topic vector (this is the segmentation) is used to calculate the Cᵥ score.